# How to add product metafeilds on any page in shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am attempting to add a product meta fields in a quick view product option on my product collection,

Here is the code I am using, the meta field in the

tag is not working

```
 {%- if collection.title == "vluevlockers"  -%}
   <div class="sizing-text">
     <h2 class="help-text">sizing information of the frames</h2>
     <p>{{ product.metafields.custom.frames_set_blueblocker }}</p>
     <div class="bold_options"> </div> 
   </div>
 {%- endif -%}
```

When I try to console.log the meta field it gives me null, But the same meta field is working fine on the single product page.

Comment: is this code inside the product loop?

Comment: yes its in btw this 
{% paginate collections.all.products by 1000 %}
 {% for product in collections.all.products %}
  
 {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}

but when I add this it shows all the meta fields of all the products.

Comment: you want for particular product or collection?

Comment: I need it for all products in a particular collection

Comment: This means to say, you said in the comment it shows all meta-fields for all products. so I ask this question to show it on a particular collection or product during listing product.